# Does dill negatively effect carrot growth?

Tags: vegetables, growth, carrots, dill

I've read in a number of [places](http://www.hpfb.org/uploads/companionplanting.pdf) that carrots and dill do not do well together.  There is no specific reason listed, so I am skeptical on this.  Looking for some hard evidence to back this up.

Answer (score 4):

Allelopathy is the ability of a plant to release substances which may inhibit the growth or germination of other plant species.

I don't know specifically about the the interaction with dill and carrots but it is possible.

Comment: Heh, Garlic and Onions can do a number on many garden vegetables. Grow them in a separate plot and allow three years before you try to plant anything else where they were planted. From direct observation... The Onion Soup smell the dirt has when you till it, it be good, but harsh on others.

Comment: Dill is reputed to retard the growth of carrots if they're planted together - what I can't find is any scientific evidence to back that up, although Michigan State University confirm that it is true in one of their publications...without giving a scientific reason.

Comment: @Bamboo a lot of the info on allelopathy is anecdotal but in the past few years there seems to be more in it for the purpose of finding companion plants that can suppress weeds in crop fields without using herbicides. I couldn't find a study on dill vs carrots but did find a mention as well http://europepmc.org/articles/PMC3249919/reload=0;jsessionid=BorOvn71axKBbh0n5YTD.24 Interesting note is that the young dill plant can help carrots by deterring the carrot root fly.